# EntityFramework Long Running ObjectContext: How to detect data source changes not tracked by the ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework

During the life of my ObjectContext, I receive a message saying telling me that a new entity has been added to the data source by some other process (i.e. not tracked by my ObjectContext). How do I add this entity to my local ObjectContext without recreating it?

I've looked at `ObjectContext.Refresh()` but I'm not sure if this is the right way forwards.

Comment: Some reading for you: Why is long living context bad - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392 and What is the purpose of self tracking entities - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091974/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-tracking-entities/5092097#5092097 . Be aware that STEs are available only in EFv4.

Comment: See my response to @DevArt regarding STEs.

Comment: Also, I long-running ObjectContexts are bad, what's the point in the DbSet.Local property. To me that implies that a long running object context is OK if we're going to bind it directly to a UI which may persist the lifetime of the application.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx

Comment: yes context can live for longer time in winform or wpf application but it is still unit of work.

Comment: So in the situation where the database changes whilst my local ObjectContext is still being used, how do I update it to reflect changes in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity is available in your code, use the [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) method.
In case this object is not available in your code, the solution is indeed to call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx) method with StoreWins RefreshMode for the collection the object was added into.
I recommend you to take a look at the [Self-Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx) as well.

Comment: I also pondered STEs but since I do have access to the ObjectContext on the same tier as my Entities, I didn't make much sense to use it. My understanding is that STEs are typically used to manipulate entities on one tier but persist those changes on another.

Comment: @Daniel, you are correct, in this case STE does not provide any additional benefits.

Comment: I finally got it to work with a combination of Attach and Refresh

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer not in the question title - long running object contexts are not a good idea in EF. Ideally the OC should be kept alive for as short a time as possible.

Comment: I kind of expected this but how do I effectively keep track of a graph of entities detached from an object context?