# Entity Framework: Attaching related objects and other state management

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have an application which uses Entity Framework Code First. I am attempting to write my resource access layer. I have several objects which all have separate database tables and a lot of object relationships. Can someone point me to an up-to-date example of CRUD methods with related objects? Everything I have found uses an older version (I use DbContext, not ObjectContext, etc.) and I am having problems writing it myself.

For example, I am currently working on an object with a parent-child relationship with itself. I am attempting to write the Create method. If I use `context.Objects.Add(newObject)` then all the children objects also have their state changed to Added, which means that duplicate children are added. So I tried looping through all the children and attaching them to the context, but then any children that did not previously exist do not get added to the database and a DbUpdateException is thrown.

Is there a generic way I can attach all related entities and have their states be correct? Any help you can give me would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

I tried explicitly loading the children using `Load()` and then adding the initial object. Unfortunately, it caused an exception because the parent comment had the child in its list of children but the parentID of the existing child had not yet been updated.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to attach whole graph and let EF automatically set correct state - [these problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) didn't changed since ObjectContext API. You must always set state manually for each entity and relation or you must build the graph from attached entities. The only exception are [Self tracking entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091974/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-tracking-entities/5092097#5092097) but they are not supported with DbContext API.