# How do I know if an object with a specified key is loaded in DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I am using Entity Framework with self-tracking POCO objects. How do I know whether an object has been loaded in the DBContext or not, without making a query... what I want to know is: *The object is loaded in memory or not?*

All my objects have `public virtual int Id {get;set;}` representing the key.

Thanks!

Comment: You said self-tracking POCO, marked your question with EF-4 and after that used `DbContext`. That makes your question quite ambiguous. So what are you using?

Comment: I use objects that don't inherit from anything, this is POCO... isn't it? They are made so that self-tracking is possible, using all virtual properties, so that Proxies can be created... and my context is inherited from DbContext, in wich I have DbSet's to make queries and get objects from DB. Did I use the wrong terminology? May be I confused some concepts!

Comment: Ok. You are using EF-4.1 and those entities are not self tracking. They only support dynamic change tracking. There is a big difference to [self-tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091974/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-tracking-entities/5092097#5092097).

Comment: If I create an object with db.Set<MyType>().Create() (db is an instance of DbContext inherited class), and then change it, are you saying that it won't track changes by itself? Could you point some good reference on this *dynamic change tracking* please? Thanks!

Comment: No it will not track changes itself. The dynamic proxy will tell the context that there was a change and context will track it. If the context is disposed tracking doesn't work but self-tracking entity is able to track changes even if the context doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if entity is tracked by your context you can use something like this:

```
bool tracked = context.ChangeTracker
                      .Entries<YourEntityType>()
                      .Any(e => e.Entity.Id == yourId);
```

Comment: Could you please quickly explain how checking if the entity is'tracked' is different from checking if the entity is 'loaded'? I mean logically from EF point of view? Thanks.