# Using STE entities in WCF Client using Java Application Client

Tags: java, wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

I have developed my DAL using Entity Framework (Self Tracking Entities). I have written a WCF Service which exposes some CRUDE operations on those STEs.

I want to use my WCF service in a java application (client).

Would the STEs work properly in my Java Client Application? I mean if the java client application makes some changes in my self tracking entity, will those changes be tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. STEs work only if you share assembly with their logic between server and client application. Once your client application is Java it cannot use your assembly with STE logic (with advanced interop it probably can but that is not solution for bad design of your service) so either Java developers must code the whole logic again or you must use plain POCOs / DTOs without this auto magic. WCF service exposing data sets or STEs is not interoperable because it demands certain logic implemented on clients.

Btw. [we warned you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642390/is-it-recommended-to-use-self-tracking-entities-with-wcf-services) about disadvantages of STEs!

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. But, isn't there any way out that we can make our java client application to use our STE entities? Thanks for the advice related to STEs also. However, can you suggest any alternative? We need to load full graph of entities and save them back to database as well.