# Entity Framework, WCF, Clients, and Object Context questions

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities, objectcontext

**Application purpose:**

The application I am creating will be responsible for many processes, but I am currently building a price feeder, a way to save these prices, and functionality to send these prices to a client application (as a proof of concept). These prices will be mapped to entities called "Security Analytics" and "Security Price Log". These two entities have the same properties, but the log keeps record of each price received, where analytics simply holds the most recent data for each security.

I am currently trying to determine the most effecient and stable way of completing this. The requirements/obstables of this are:

- Prices come in very frequently (will sometimes receive multiple prices every second)
- Client's require realtime data
- Prices need to be persisted to the database each time they come in

**Architecture:**

I belieive this application is suited towards an n-tier architecture. The layers I am thinking of including are (pardon my naming of these):

- **Entity layer:** where model is constructed
- **"Factory":** this will contain my feeds (there will be approximately 10), logic for processing data, conversion of data to entities, and allow for exposure of data to clients
- **Client layer:** I want to the factory to expose data contracts to allow clients to consume the real time data within the factory. I done some research and I will complete this through WCF web services using a Pub-Sub design pattern

So with all of that background information and rambling here are my questions:

- What are the disadvantages to having a long running object context? (I kept reading that I shouldn't do this, but no one explicitly said why or gave alternatives that will work for me)
- If I am constantly creating new contexts, is the data I have pulled into a previous context available in a new context? I am concerned that I will be pulling data from the database too often when I am pushing data to clients and processing many new prices.
- I am currently using self-tracking entities and think they are the correct choice for this application, but if anyone has any concerns or wisdom they could provide, that would be appreciated.
- Lastly, what would be the best type of project for creating my "factory"? It will be running on an IIS server and I would like it to accept all of my data feeds and have clients accepting different and composite (from multiple feeds) data. I am leaning towards a WCF Service Application as it will allow me to easily derive service contracts, but I am not sure if this is the correct choice.

Any help you can provide with this is appreciated. Also, I appologize for the length of this, I am just quite lost as to how the entity framework works and where I should start. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for your responses everyone. I have to move onto something else for now, but I will review these later this week when I have a chance.

Comment: I am open to this, but we have begun work in .Net/C#. Do you have any resources where I can do some research?

Comment: @paulsm4: I see some background behind your claim but without explaining it, it is just rant to start flame war.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too complex. This kind of questions usually doesn't have satisfying answer because it is too open ended and it also requires much deeper analysis of your requirements.

Few thoughts about your sub questions:

- Long running context can be significant problem. It has a [lot of disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392) (single shared instance per context, single shared unit of work per context, not thread safe) so make sure you think about all of them before you really choose to use it. Long running context can be still used  if you use it as single unit of work - this usually happens in thick clients where your context lives as long as your UI window.
- No. Data pulled from one context must be manually attached to another context or loaded from database again. They are not tracked by a new context instance automatically but it is not clear why are you concern about this because of your next question.
- STEs have their [pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642390/is-it-recommended-to-use-self-tracking-entities-with-wcf-services). They can [solve quite complex problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) but in the same time they tightly couples your client and service. They can also significantly increase amount of transferred data when you transfer object graphs because the supposed scenario is to get object graph and return that graph back to service even if you changed just single relation. [I'm not big fan of STEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968).
- Pub-Sub pattern and your real time data requirement: This is something where some more suitable technology should be used. I used JMS (not available in .NET directly unless you use API from some JMS provider like IBM XMS or Apache NMS) / Tibco EMS and Tibco Randezvous previously and if I compare Pub-Sub pattern available in WCF with real Pub-Sub infrastructures the WCF implementation is like a bad joke. Too complex, too slow and with a lot of pitfalls because it is missing messaging middleware. If your application is business critical, you have a good budget (or existing enterprise infrastructure using some messaging solution) and your real time data requirement is serious you should investigate these possibilities. I didn't try it yet but RabbitMQ should offer Pub-Sub infrastructure as well.

Comment: We are using RabbitMQ for pushing prices to this application (from a c++ feed), so this could be an option. I like WCF web services for the ease of connection between different clients (excel, silverlight, console), but I will look into the options you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a publish/subscribe model is good.  However you don't need to constantly pull data.

All of your clients become listeners.
The push event when new prices come in include price changes in the event argument model.
Not sure if you need "factory" models.

For the entity framework, short-lived context are always best way to go.  While you may create many over a short period of time, the framework retrieves them from a connection pool.

Each context holds a connection to the database which is always viewed as a rare resource.  You should hole rare resources for the shortest period of time.

When you create a new context, and you are passed an object, you meerly issue an Attach to rebind the object to the context.  It actually binds to the appropriate table the object lives in.

Your WCF services are the best and most performant way to go.  But instead of factories you are basically writing services.

For your clients:
  At startup call serviceContext.GetInitialPrices and you get all prices as of that moment.
  Subscribe to get price changes

For your service:
  Whenever the source of price changes hits you:
       create context
       attach each price record
       call SaveChanges on the context

```
   Publish changes of the array of prices that have changed.
```

Your bigger question then is deciding on what you will use for publish/subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. In a test project, I used WCF web services to set up the pub/sub pattern. It was quite painful to get working, but once I overcame the obstacles it is quite easy to use. There are limitations, and I agree with Ladislav that there are many pitfalls, so do you have any suggestions for an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very straight-forward that if you're concerned about making too many database calls, you'll have to consider caching data in your middle-tier and possibly on the client.

If you're thinking about using the Entity Framework, that sounds like a great idea.  At the shop where I work, we don't use all the latest .net toys from Microsoft; once I got my hands on Entity Framework, I could hardly believe how much simpler my data layer became.  It will automate, for you, hours upon hours of tedious, error-prone data layer programming.