# Can I use Self Tracking Entities and DBContext in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, self-tracking-entities, dbcontext

I want to know if DBContext (EF 4.1) supports Self Tracking Entities. If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unless you rewrite the template to support them. The current template is dependent on ObjectContext API.